# Ошибка компиляции protoc на windows

Tags: golang, google-protobuf, grpc

пытаюсь разобраться в gRPC-go, но не могу корректно установить компилятор protoc. Файл protoc.exe лежит в %GOPATH%/bin, также я положил его в Git/usr/bin. Папку inlcude, которая была в архиве protoc-3.5.1-win32.zip я положил в Git/usr/local (папку local создал ручками) и после ввода команды мне выдаёт вот такую ошибку (если делать через командную строку, то там также непонятная кодировка).

[image: GIT-bash]

В файле *.proto не должно быть никаких ошибок, прилагаю сам файл:
[image: session.proto]

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Я догадываюсь конечно, что положил папку inlcude не туда, но никакой информации я не нашёл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если выполнить указанную вами команду в простой windows консоли, то вы получите вполне читаемое сообщение об ошибке:

```
b:\>protoc --go_out=. test.proto
"protoc-gen-go" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

Дело в том, что в `protoc` нету *встроенного* генератора для go. Генерация возможно только через *плагин* `protoc-gen-go`, который **нужно устанавливать отдельно**. Делается это вот такой командой:

```
go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
```

После того, как плагин установится, вы можете использовать генератор для go.

Comment: Большое спасибо, проблема решилась.